# Checkout to previous commit and push to server to check behaviour, return to actual commit and push actual state again

Tags: git

I have to check the behaviour of my website in the server on a previous state. My idea is to go to the previous commit in local version, push, and see how the site was working in the server in that previous version; then I want to return to actual state in local, and update the server as well.

```
git checkout [commit_ref] // Go to previous commit in local
git push // Send to server and check the website
git checkout [branch_name] // Return to last commit in local
git push // Update the server
```

Is this done this way? I heard about `git revert`, but I don't know why I should use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend learning the basics behind how git works. This will likely answer your question.

Comment: I have been using git for six months; I know how to push, navigate between branches, etc. Sadly your advice, being right, is absolutely empty. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush. “Think like a git”, and “git for ages 4 and up” are both vital starts to understanding git.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting your actual production website to look for a problem which might have occurred in the past sounds like an all around bad idea.  What I suggest is just checking out an old commit locally, poking around, and then returning to the HEAD of your branch once you are done:

```
git checkout <old commit>
# poke around
git checkout branch_name   # return to the branch
```

With regard to what you do upon finding a bug, it depends on the situation.  You might just make a new commit which fixes the bug.  If one or more old commits are found to be completely rancid, then you might choose to `git revert` those commits.

Comment: Thanks! I know that I can use `checkout` to go to a past commit, but… if I push, the server will be set in this commit as well?

Comment: I am telling you _not_ to push an outdated branch to your server.  Just test locally and make changes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to checkout if all you want is push. Just push the commit:

```
git push origin oldcommit:remote_branch
```

That's all! To return to the head of the branch push the head:

```
git push origin local_branch:remote_branch
```